# How to update backend bean with multiple rows selected in prime faces sheet

Tags: jsf-2.2, primefaces-extensions

I am using primefaces 6.2.3 sheet component. I am trying to update the backing bean when the user selects multiple rows and clicks on context menu. I am not able to retrieve the rows selected in my bean.  The primefaces extension example uses JavaScript to remove the rows selected from UI without calling the backing bean.

Comment: You **can** call a remote command from javascript

Answer (score 0):

As @Kukeltje has stated simply use a primefaces p:remoteCommand and you can use that in your Javascript code to executing backing bean methods.